# Opening PDFs using Treeview

Tags: class, pdf, tkinter, treeview, filepath

I have a file on my desktop that has over 100 subfolders all branching out to organize a ton of PDFs. I'm trying to make an app that uses a GUI to better access and open these PDFs. Treeview would be perfect, but I can't figure out how to actually open files using anything but a button. Can someone please tell me how to use these to find a filepath and open a pdf? Thanks.

EDIT:

basically, I have a tree that looks like this:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(vender_class)
tree.pack(fill=BOTH)
tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=1, text="Thresholds")
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=2, text="Butt Hung")
tree.insert(parent='2', index='end', iid=3, text="THBH")
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=4, text="Center Hung")
tree.insert(parent='4', index='end', iid=5, text="THCH")
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=6, text="Offset Hung")
tree.insert(parent='6', index='end', iid=7, text="THOH")
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=8, text="Other")
tree.insert(parent='8', index='end', iid=9, text="THO")

open_button=ttk.Button(vender_class, text="Open PDF", command=openfile)
open_button.pack()
```

I would prefer being able to simply double click the end item (i.e. "THBH") and it open the PDF on Bluebeam. If that can't work then how do you link it to the button so that if "THBH" is selected and the button is pushed, it opens the PDF that way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attach a specific tag for the rows which will open PDF when double-clicked.

Then bind double-click event on the `Treeview` widget and then in the callback check whether the double-clicked item has the specific tag. If it has, open the PDF file based on the `text` of the clicked item.

```py
tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=1, text="Thresholds")
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=2, text="Butt Hung")
tree.insert(parent='2', index='end', iid=3, text="THBH", tags='pdf')
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=4, text="Center Hung")
tree.insert(parent='4', index='end', iid=5, text="THCH", tags='pdf')
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=6, text="Offset Hung")
tree.insert(parent='6', index='end', iid=7, text="THOH", tags='pdf')
tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=8, text="Other")
tree.insert(parent='8', index='end', iid=9, text="THO", tags='pdf')

def on_double_click(event):
    iid = tree.focus() # get the iid of the selected item
    tags = tree.item(iid, 'tags') # get tags attached
    if 'pdf' in tags:
        text = tree.item(iid, 'text') # get the text of selected item
        print('open PDF for', text)
        # open PDF based on text
        ...

tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', on_double_click)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great! I modified it a little so I don't need to add the tags (the example tree I gave was the smallest one out of over 50) but it works exactly how I need it to. Thanks again!